# Arquillian Drone + Selenium Grid 2.0: Keep unused Browser alive

Tags: java, selenium, jboss-arquillian

I am using Arquillian Drone + Graphene (standalone) for driving automated Browser Tests on a Selenium Grid 2.0 hosted on another machine. The tests are run via Arquillian in client mode (the server to be tested is already running)

Some of my tests require using two browsers at once, therefore i added a second Browser according to the [Graphene Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQGRA2/Parallel+browsers).
So far everything is working.

The Problem:
Running a test which has both browsers injected has both of them started up before any test of the class is run. As there may be a few tests before the second browser is used, it most likely has already timed out.
Of course i could set the Selenium Grid Settings to never (or very late) close the browser via timeout, but that cannot be the solution.

Is there a way to check if the WebDriver is still up and restart it via Drone?

Without Drone i simply could check if the driver quit ([e.g. like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27616470/webdriver-how-to-check-if-browser-still-exists-or-still-open)) and create a new instance. But i want to have it injected via Drone.

In the best case i would like to be able to define when Drone should open the browser or even better keep it open until the test is finished.
If thats not possible a way to restart it would be sufficient.

Comment: For more info on Arquillinan Graphene: http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automation-using-arquillian-framework/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem by directly injecting the WebDriver into the test method.

```
public void test(@Drone @Browser2 WebDriver webdriver){...}
```

I am still not completely happy with this solution but it does work.