# selenium: What if user close the browser or webdriver? how can I detect if the browser is closed?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenide

> - OS:Window 10
> - Browser: Chrome webDriver
> - Browser Version: Chrome 63.0.3239.10(64bit)
> - Selenium Version 2.44

Added below dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.44.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Expected Behavior -

I want check if the driver is closed by user directly, and restart the webdriver if there is no browser.

Before `Driver webdriver = new ChromeDriver()` codes, the webdriver is null state,

but after `Driver webdriver = new ChromeDriver()` code finished, even if user close the browser, webdriver is not destroyed.

so, after user close the browser, all code related to webdriver has the error:: "unreachable Exception".

I want restart the webdriver, if the browser is closed by user, but I can not detect the situation.

1. `driver!=null` code is not working, because driver still exist after browser is closed by user
2. `if((driver.getWindowHandle().equals(""))` is not working, because Chrome Unreachable Exception, because browser is closed by user

What I want to do is to check if the browser is gone, because of user?

Comment: Hi. Did you check this answer? You may find something using the toString() method (`driver.toString().contains("null")`) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27616470/webdriver-how-to-check-if-browser-still-exists-or-still-open

Comment: But what remains unclear to me is how we can check whether the browser were closed *by the user*... Selenium will close it, but not like a "real user".

Answer (score 7):

You can perform any action on driver object, if it is throwing UnreachableBrowserException, then there is problem to communicate with the browser.

The most common causes for this exception are:

1. The provided server address to RemoteWebDriver is invalid, so the connection could not be established.
2. The browser has died mid-test.

And you can call the following method to verify the browser is closed or not.

```cs
public boolean isBrowserClosed(WebDriver driver)
{
    boolean isClosed = false;
    try {
        driver.getTitle();
    } catch(UnreachableBrowserException ubex) {
        isClosed = true;
    }

    return isClosed;
}
```

Comment: other commands can be used to check if the browser is alive too, e.g. cookie retrieval.

Answer (score -1):

Addressing your queries:

- *What if user close the browser or webdriver* : First of all *automated test execution* shouldn't be interuptted by *manual intervention*. It's against all the *best practices*. If you forcefully close the *Web Browser* then *WebDriver* will throw *`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException`* as follows :

  ```
   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Process unexpectedly closed with status: 0
   Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
   System info: host: 'foo', ip: 'foo', os.name: 'foo', os.arch: 'foo', os.version: 'foo', java.version: 'foo'
   Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
   remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
      0:           0x47e934 - <no info>
      1:           0x47f0a3 - <no info>
      2:           0x442649 - <no info>
      3:           0x449cc3 - <no info>
      4:           0x42a890 - <no info>
      5:           0x406f5e - <no info>
      6:           0x40cfc9 - <no info>
      7:           0x6bef19 - <no info>
      8:           0x420756 - <no info>
      9:           0x6b96e0 - <no info>
     10:      0x7fa0fb01842 - BaseThreadInitThunk
  ```
- *How can I detect if the browser is closed?* : If the *Automation Script* handles proper *initiation* and *closure* of *Web Browser* you don't need to explicitly validate if _browser is closed or not. Cross checking dead *Web Browser* and *Web Browser* session / chores would be a pure overhead. So a better practice would be to write clean code
- *Restart the webdriver if there is no browser* : Should be handled by the *Automation Script* through *WebDriver* and *Web Browser* initialization.
- *User close the browser, webdriver is not destroyed* : As you *WebDriver* and *Web Browser* was started through you *Automation Script* an user closing the *Web Browser* would be a *malpractice*. *Web Browser* closure must be handled by the the *Automation Script*.
- *I want restart the webdriver* : Neither you can connect to the previous instance of the *WebDriver* nor to the previous instance of the *Web Browser*. You have to reinitialize again as follows :

  ```
   WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver();
  ```

> See the discussion [How can I reconnect to the browser opened by webdriver with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861813/how-can-i-reconnect-to-the-browser-opened-by-webdriver-with-selenium/47862867#47862867) for details.